# Fatal: command argument is too long

Tags: c++, bitcoind

So, over the past few days I have been attempting to make litecoind on windows(mingw.) Last night I got an error saying: Fatal command argument is too long.
The following is the output:

> make -f makefile.mingw USE_UPNP=-
>   MAKE Version 4.0  Copyright (c) 1987, 1996 Borland International
>          g++ -mthreads -O2 -w -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-unuse
>   d-parameter -g -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS -DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB -DBOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSA
>   FE -DUSE_IPV6 -D__NO_SYSTEM_INCLUDES -I"C:\deps\boost"  -I"C:\deps\db\build_unix
>   "  -I"C:\deps\ssl\include" -o foocoin.exe -L"C:\deps\boost\stage\lib"  -L"C:\dep
>   s\db\build_unix"  -L"C:\deps\ssl" $ -l boost_system-mgw46-mt-s-1_49  -l boost_fi
>   lesystem-mgw46-mt-s-1_49  -l boost_program_options-mgw46-mt-s-1_49  -l boost_thr
>   ead-mgw46-mt-s-1_49  -l db_cxx  -l ssl  -l crypto
>   Fatal: Command arguments too long

Comment: error message seems descriptive..It says you gave too much arguments to your command. problem can be the - characters..please check commands help and rewrite your arguments according to that..try to use "" whenever possible etc

Comment: Is there a way to increase the amount of characters per command?

Comment: I am just guessing so, it will helpful for you to google it.

Comment: The search results say the issue only appears on win 98 :(

Comment: so it is the time for you to move on at least win XP :)